# Auth Guard with promise

Tags: authentication, promise, angular7, guard, aws-amplify

I am using the AWS amplify for the login for the angular project. I want the user redirect to the login page if its not logged in, and if its logged and purchase flag is false then its should redirect to the checkout page. for this requirement I have used Auth guard. but its goes in infinite loop.

Please suggest

```
  canActivate(): Promise < boolean > {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser({
          bypassCache: false
        })
        .then((user) => {

           localStorage.setItem('UserAttributes',JSON.stringify(user.attributes));
           localStorage.setItem('IsPurchased',user.attributes["custom:IsPurchased"]);
           localStorage.setItem('userGroup',user.signInUserSession.idToken.payload['cognito:groups']);
           let IsPurchased=localStorage.getItem('IsPurchased');
           let userGroup=localStorage.getItem('userGroup');
          if(user){

                if(IsPurchased=='0')
                {
                  this.router.navigate(['/checkout']);
                   return Promise.resolve(false);
                }else{
                    return Promise.resolve(true);
                }

            } 
        })
        .catch((errr) => {

             this.router.navigate(['/login']);
              return Promise.resolve(false);

        });
    });
  }
```

Comment: The returned promise never settles; Neither `resolve` (nor `reject`) is ever called. In any case, the `new Promise()` wrapper is unnecessary; simply `return Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser(...).then(...);`. That alone may fix the issue.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply!

I have modified the code as per your comment but no luck.
I have resolve this issue by adding two guard.
 one for checking user is logged in or not and 2nd one for checking purchase flag.

Comment: Sounds like that's probably a better solution as long as the logged-in guard is guaranteed to have priority over checking purchase flag. I expect your "all-in-one" could be made to work but I don't know AWS amplify well enough to advise further.